# What is the correct Job's name to delete old builds but working with Folders?

Tags: jenkins

I read these links:

- [Clear Jenkins build history ( clear build yesterday )](https://superuser.com/questions/1418885/clear-jenkins-build-history-clear-build-yesterday)
- [How do I delete the builds 11 to 1717 in Jenkins?](https://superuser.com/questions/589528/how-do-i-delete-the-builds-11-to-1717-in-jenkins)
- [Jenkins: remove old builds with command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052390/jenkins-remove-old-builds-with-command-line)

First of all I work around `Folders` and these contains `Views` and these `Jobs` respectively.

Consider the following (to keep it simple):

- **Folder**: `jenkins-01` **View**: alpha **Job**: Execute
- **Folder**: `jenkins-02` **View**: betax **Job**: Execute

From above two important observations:

- The `jenkins-01` and `jenkins-02` *folders* are for two different projects.
- The `Execute` *Job* , can be repeated in many different *Folders*, but only about the name.

Now consider the following:

I can execute the `Job` through:

No *custom* `View` - therefore the default `All` default/generic view:

- `http://localhost:9090/job/jenkins-01/job/Execute/`

Through many Views, let's say

- `http://localhost:9090/job/jenkins-01/view/alpha/job/Execute/`
- `http://localhost:9090/job/jenkins-01/view/betax/job/Execute/`

And all the history or track of builds are in this path location:

- `/Users/username/ci/jenkins/Contents/jobs/jenkins-01/jobs/Execute`

### Script Console

Through the following:

```
def jobName = ???

println jobName;

//I used any of them
//def job = Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName(jobName, Job.class)
//def job = Jenkins.instance.getItem(jobName)

if(job != null) {
     job.getBuilds().each { println it }  
   //job.getBuilds().each { it.delete() }  
   //job.nextBuildNumber = 1   
   //job.save()
}
else
    println 'job is NULL'
```

I tried many combinations about `jobName` (it about `???`) and always I get `null`. So what should be the correct value for `jobName`?

### Command Line

- `java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:9090 delete-builds jobName=??? '1-56'`

Again: what should be the correct value `jobName`?.

**Remember:** each `Job` is declared in a `Folder` and the Job's name (just the name) can be repeated in many `Folders`

Comment: Hi, if the answer satisfies your question, consider marking as accepted (tick mark) or ask if you need more detail.

Comment: Understood, but to complete the idea, your snippet code where should be used? A figure about that would improve your answer.

Comment: @IanW remember that the Jenkins instance has many `folders`, so consider to improve your answer: it about the code to isolate/select a specific `folder` and **then** list the `Jobs` from that `Folder`. It because exists a high likely or risk to have many `Folders` with `Jobs` with the same name

Comment: Answer expanded upon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only only authoritative path for a job - it is `job.fullName`; that is

`http://localhost:9090/job/jenkins-01/job/Execute/`

This will give you the `fullName` of all your jobs:

```
Jenkins.instance.allItems.findAll() 
    { it instanceof AbstractProject }.each 
    {println it.fullName}
```

Views are merely filtered lists of jobs to be displayed. You should see the same job history in every View.

**NB:** It is unfortunate Jenkins allows jobs with the same name as if you "move" a job, you could clobber another in another folder with the same name.

**Update:** The following code will select all "top-level" folders and iterate thru them, listing the contents of each. Conditions to (or not) recursively process are noted. There is only ever one handle to a job and that is `it.fullName`.

You can add additional conditions to limit the scope to specific folders or job name patterns.

```
import com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.*

Folders =  Jenkins.instance.allItems.findAll() 
    { it instanceof com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder && !it.fullName.contains("/")  
    // remove the && condition to retrieve nested folders
}

Folders.collect { folder ->
  println "::: " + folder.fullName
    // use folder.getItems().findAll() below to not recurse into nested folders
    folder.allItems.findAll()
    { it instanceof AbstractProject }.each 
    { println folder.fullName + ' - ' + it.fullName }
}
return
```